# Prevent Rotation on ViewController

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, rotation

How can I prevent the rotation on one `UIViewController` by code  ?
in more words I want to prevent rotation for one `UIViewController` not for all

Comment: possible duplicate of [disable autorotate on a single UIViewController in iOS6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370806/disable-autorotate-on-a-single-uiviewcontroller-in-ios6)

Answer (score 1):

You need to subclass the view controller, and then return NO from shouldAutoRotate

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotate

Answer (score 1):

In Your view controller

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

return YES;

}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

}