# how can i do landscape disable for just one viewController iOS

Tags: ios, orientation

my project have UITabbar, UınavigationBar and UIViewContoller.

```
-UITabbar
 —UINavigationController
   —UIViewController
```

Question: how can i do landscape disable just one viewController? i want to only portrait view but for just one view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [disable autorotate on a single UIViewController in iOS6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370806/disable-autorotate-on-a-single-uiviewcontroller-in-ios6)

Comment: yes.Succesed. Other solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14738180/3215402

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>[disable autorotate on a single UIViewController in iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370806/disable-autorotate-on-a-single-uiviewcontroller-in-ios6)</strike>

Add this to your app delegate

```
- (NSUInteger) application:(UIApplication *)application     supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

if ([[window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[YourViewController class]])
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
else
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I recently found out about this, and it has been working perfectly for me. Add this code to your view controller

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

And in your `viewWillAppear` add

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    ///Disable orientation changes
    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
}
```

Comment: Partially Working. If I move back from Landscape ViewController to Portrait ViewController. It was not giving desired result. Please give feedback if you have any solution for that

Comment: @LeoMoon85 Answer updated. Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: I also add one more thing...in viewDidAppear, [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO]; and again [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES]; in viewWillAppear. It helps viewing better when moving back from landscape to portrait and vise versa. Thx.