# iOS: Disable autoRotating for UIViewController presented Modally

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am making iOS SDK which will be used to add functionalities to client's app. My SDK will be presenting views modally over the top current view of the client's app. I am using below snippet to present view modally

```
sdkViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
[currentAppViewController presentViewController:sdkViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Here, I want to **Fix the orientation of my sdkViewController(and subviews) to Portrait mode** 
I have tried to implement this

Inside **sdkViewController.m**

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
     return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

But no success. After going through [disable autorotate on a single UIViewController in iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370806/disable-autorotate-on-a-single-uiviewcontroller-in-ios6), and similar posts, almost all insisted to subclass the **UINavigationController** and override the *shouldAutorotate* and *supportedInterfaceOrientations* in the subclass.

> I have No Navigation controller before first ViewController, I just present my sdkViewController modally over the top most view of the client's app.

After hours of googling, i was convienced that the the three methods i have try to implement in **sdkViewController.m**, are useless because this methods are called inside **rootViewController**, not inside any childViewController.
Please help me find a way to fix the orientation of views persented modally over the view where i have no juridiction.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the parent using .presentingViewController property? Modifying that viewcontroller's autorotate properties, or a callback method?

Comment: I should not modify parent view controller. As it would have client's preferences.

Comment: Any tab bar controller, navigation controller or container keep `sdkViewController` ?